# How does VMware configure X11? Autosize Error.

Tags: linux, vmware, xorg

Host: VMWare Workstation 12 Player 12.5.5 Windows 10

Guest: Debian 8 Jessie, Awesome WM

I have been trying to track down a configuration bug that suddenly appeared in a VM I use where the autofit feature of vmware-tools stopped working. The resolution is fixed at 800x600 after the autosize stopped working. If I

```
xrandr --size 1360x768
```

it will change resolution to the new resolution. The list of resolutions output in `xrandr` does not include the native resolution of the LCD which is 1600x1200. I have tried many other solutions to similar types of questions on the net but nothing has solved my problem. I removed X11 and reinstalled it, removed open-vm-tools-desktop and reinstalled, same with the VMware provided version of vmware-tools. Finally I have another debian vm which is nearly identical on this host which has `xrandr` showing a more complete list of resolutions and has the autofit feature working.
I was hoping to get the autofit feature working again without having to do create a new vm.

Answer (score 1):

Recently the same happened to me, but I've managed to find a culprit because I use 2 different .vmx files for the same guest (linux is placed on the USB drive) to run it on 2 different computers and fortunately only the 1 file got corrupted. After comparing both files, it turned out, it is only necessary to remove the following lines from the .vmx file and it starts to work again:

```
svga.guestBackedPrimaryAware = "TRUE"
svga.maxWidth = "1920"
svga.maxHeight = "1080"
svga.autodetect = "TRUE"
svga.vramSize = "134217728"
```